# Jquery error placement with html

Tags: jquery, html

I am using validator plugin in my form. I am having 3 sets of radio buttons and 1 set of checkbox. I am using error placement for radio and checkboxes such that if error occurs it put error class next to particular error element.

```
        errorElement: "div",
        wrapper: "div",  // a wrapper around the error message
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if(element.is(":radio")){
                error.insertAfter('ul.radio');
                error.addClass('error_class');
            }else if(element.is(":checkbox")){
                error.insertAfter('ul.checkbox');
                error.addClass('error_class');
            } else{
                error.insertAfter(element);
                error.addClass('error_class');
            }
        },
```

It works fine if I have single checkbox and radio group but if I have 3 radio group and this generate 3 error sets next to each radio group having class radio. Like this...

my next CSS is like this...

```
<div class="sgnup-cnt-inpt1">
                    <h3>Type of Classes *</h3>
                    <ul class="lst1 radio">
                        <li>
                            <span><input type="radio" class="required error" value="Academic" id="type_of_class_a" name="type_of_class"></span>
                            <label>Academic</label>
                        </li><li>
                            <span><input type="radio" class="required error" value="Non-Academic" id="type_of_class_n" name="type_of_class"></span>
                            <label> Non-academic</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
<div><div htmlfor="teaching_exp" generated="true" class="error" style="display: block;">Required.</div></div>
<div><div htmlfor="type_of_class" generated="true" class="error" style="display: block;">Required.</div></div>
<div><div htmlfor="gender" generated="true" class="error" style="display: block;">Required.</div></div><div style="display: none;"><div htmlfor="type_of_class_insti" generated="true" class="error" style="display: none;">Required.</div></div>
                    <div id="radio"></div>
                </div>
```

**NOTE** I don't wish to use if else in each case radio's error placement. I want to use globally for `:radio`. I don't wish to compare it with name and other attributes.

Comment: Please add a link to plugin, there's not only one validator plugon out there...

Comment: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Well did you manage it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting the occurred error after every `ul` element with the specified class and not only to the corresponding one. Try:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if(element.is(":radio")){
        error.insertAfter(element.closest('ul.radio'));
        error.addClass('error_class');
    } else if(element.is(":checkbox")){
        error.insertAfter(element.closest('ul.checkbox'));
        error.addClass('error_class');
    } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
        error.addClass('error_class');
    }
},
```

So the error only get appended to the `ul` related to the error element.